# Не могу избавиться от полей вокруг wrapper

Tags: html, css

Я хочу сделать слайдер для мобильной версии; Все вроде бы подготовил, но сталкиваюсь с тем, что по левую и правую стороны от wrapper у меня возникает свободное пространство (и немного снизу). Смотрю  в developer tools - высвечивает margin у wrapper, но его там нет, и даже если специально прописать нулевые margin, пространство не уходит. Что делать? В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал добавлять и 0-вой margin body, ничего не изменилось.

Слайды заменил цветными квадратами, все равно от них тут разницы никакой нет.

Заранее спасибо!

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: :'Geometria-Medium';
  src: url('../fonts/Geometria-Medium.otf') format('otf');
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: :'Geometria';
  src: url('../fonts/Geometria.otf') format('otf');
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: :'Philosopher';
  src: url('../fonts/Philosopher-Bold.otf') format('otf');
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  body {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: url('../img/bg-desktop@1x.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 84px;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -505px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 70px;
    z-index: 12;
  }
  .visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .main-nav {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
  }
  .main-nav__toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 168px;
    right: 90px;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    background: url('../img/burger-menu.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .site-wrapper {
    width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .slider {
    position: relative;
  }
  .slider__first-slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    height: 525px;
    left: 72px;
    top: 166px;
    background-image: url('../img/hall.jpg');
  }
  .slider__first-slide::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7e611;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  .slider__second-slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 860px;
    height: 490px;
    top: 251px;
    right: 88px;
    background-image: url('../img/motorbike.jpg');
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .slider__second-slide::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7e611;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  .first-image {
    background-image: url('../img/hall.jpg');
  }
  .second-image {
    background-image: url('../img/motorbike.jpg');
  }
  .yellow-rectangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 322px;
    right: calc(50% - 431px);
    width: 138px;
    height: 383px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 88px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #f7e611;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__thirteen {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
    left: 23px;
    font-size: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 4.5px;
    font-family: "Geometria";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: normal;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__thirteen::after {
    position: relative;
    content: "";
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3px;
    right: -4px;
    width: 17px;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__seven {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    left: 78px;
    font-family: "Geometria";
    font-size: 17px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1.7px;
    line-height: normal;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__nav-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: -35px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url('../img/left-arrow.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__nav-forward {
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    right: -40px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url('../img/right-arrow.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .text {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .text__test {
    left: -36px;
    top: 460px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.44px;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.4;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  .text__number {
    left: calc(50% - 505px);
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #000000;
  }
  .text__number--1 {
    top: 248px;
  }
  .text__number--3 {
    top: 329px;
  }
  .text__big-number {
    top: 194px;
    left: calc(50% - 168px);
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 2.8px;
    color: #000000;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .text__circle {
    padding: 22px 22px;
    top: 284px;
    left: calc(50% - 141px);
    width: 85px;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.41;
    letter-spacing: 2.14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url('../img/circle-design.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .text__slogan {
    left: calc(50% - 446px);
    top: 550px;
    font-family: 'Philosopher';
    font-size: 9px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .rectangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 333px;
    left: calc(50% - 380px);
    width: 177px;
    height: 282px;
    background: url('../img/rectangle-design.png');
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .olive-branch {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .olive-branch__pic {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: calc(50% - 60px);
  }
  .olive-branch::after {
    background-color: #f8eb4c;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    left: calc(50% - 213px/2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 112px;
    width: 213px;
  }
  .letters__design {
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--big {
    top: 105px;
    right: 405px;
    font-family: 'Geometria-Medium';
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 117px;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--medium {
    top: 80px;
    left: 25px;
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--small--first {
    bottom: -65px;
    right: calc(50% + 445px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--small--second {
    bottom: -45px;
    right: calc(50% - 218px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .letters__letter-f--first {
    bottom: -30px;
    right: calc(50% + 383px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .letters__letter-f--second {
    bottom: -75px;
    right: calc(50% + 320px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .letters__letter-e--big {
    top: 185px;
    right: 240px;
    font-family: 'Geometria-Medium';
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 117px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .letters__letter-e--small {
    bottom: -80px;
    right: calc(50% - 430px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .letters__letter-g--big {
    top: 265px;
    right: 320px;
    font-family: 'Geometria-Medium';
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 117px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .letters__letter-g--small {
    bottom: -51px;
    right: calc(50% - 321px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .letters__letter-i {
    bottom: -45px;
    right: calc(50% + 265px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .letters__letter-n {
    bottom: -87px;
    right: calc(50% + 190px);
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .triangle {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .triangle__light-first {
    bottom: -102px;
    left: calc(50% - 277px);
  }
  .triangle__light-second {
    bottom: -73px;
    right: calc(50% - 261px);
  }
  .triangle__dark-first {
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 185px;
  }
  .triangle__dark-second {
    bottom: -53px;
    right: 224px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1439px) {
  .logo,
  .yellow-rectangle__seven,
  .letters__letter-a--small--first,
  .letters__letter-a--small--second,
  .letters__letter-e--small,
  .letters__letter-g--small,
  .letters__letter-f--first,
  .letters__letter-f--second,
  .letters__letter-i,
  .letters__letter-n,
  .text__circle,
  .text__test,
  .text__number--3,
  .text__number--1,
  .text__big-number,
  .rectangle,
  .triangle__dark-second,
  .triangle__light-second,
  .olive-branch__pic {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #f7e611;
  }
  .visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .site-wrapper {
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  .slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .slider__first-slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 236px;
    height: 184px;
    margin-bottom: -17px;
    margin-top: 88px;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
  }
  .slider__first-slide::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7e611;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  .slider__second-slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 318px;
    background-color: green;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .slider__second-slide::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7e611;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  .letters__design {
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .main-nav__toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url('../img/burger-menu-mob.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .main-nav__toggle::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 177px;
    height: 282px;
    top: -115px;
    right: -96px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url('../img/rectangle-design.png');
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .letters__letter-e--big {
    top: 132px;
    right: 66px;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .letters__letter-g--big {
    top: 210px;
    right: 128px;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--big {
    top: 226px;
    left: 68px;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 6;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--medium {
    top: 0px;
    left: 17px;
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__thirteen {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 17px;
    right: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: "Geometria";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__thirteen::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 106px;
    height: 106px;
    bottom: -18px;
    right: -21px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url('../img/Rectangle_20.png');
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  .olive-branch::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 105px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 53px;
    z-index: 15;
    background: url('../img/olive-branch-mob.svg');
  }
  .triangle {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .triangle__light-first {
    bottom: 29px;
    left: 43px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .triangle__dark-first {
    top: 231px;
    right: 30px;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__nav-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 17px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 36px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background: url('../img/left-arrow.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    z-index: 15;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__nav-forward {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    right: 22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 36px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background: url('../img/right-arrow.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    z-index: 15;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .text__slogan {
    position: absolute;
    left: -23px;
    top: 245px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-family: 'Philosopher';
    font-size: 9px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000000;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    z-index: 15;
  }
  .first-image {
    background-image: url('../img/hall.jpg');
  }
  .second-image {
    background-image: url('../img/motorbike.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Affinage</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <button class="main-nav__toggle" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Открыть меню</span></button>
    </nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <svg class="logo__image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="988" height="99" viewBox="0 0 988 99">
      <g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <text dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" style="font-kerning:normal" fill="#fff" font-family="'Philosopher','Philosopher'" font-size="140" font-style="none" font-weight="400" letter-spacing="50.4" transform="translate(-3 -30)">
          <tspan>AFFINAGE</tspan>
         </text>
        </g>
       </g>
      </g>
     </svg>
    </div>
    <section class="slider">
      <div class="slider__first-slide">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__second-slide">
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="yellow-rectangle">
      <span class="yellow-rectangle__thirteen">13</span>
      <span class="yellow-rectangle__seven">7</span>
      <button class="yellow-rectangle__nav-back" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Назад</span></button>
      <button class="yellow-rectangle__nav-forward" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Вперед</span></button>
    </div>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--big">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--medium">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--small--first">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--small--second">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-e--big">e</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-e--small">e</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-g--big">g</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-g--small">g</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-f--first">f</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-f--second">f</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-i">i</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-n">n</span>
    <span class="text text__circle">ural 03</span>
    <span class="text text__test">тестовое задание</span>
    <span class="text text__slogan">очень хороший слоган</span>
    <span class="text text__number text__number--3">(3)</span>
    <span class="text text__number text__number--1">(1)</span>
    <span class="text text__big-number">51</span>
    <span class="rectangle"><h2 class="visually-hidden">Четырехугольник для декорации</h2></span>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__dark-first" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="#131212" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814h-1.028L.377 24.027H23.18v-.822"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__dark-second" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="#131212" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814h-1.028L.377 24.027H23.18v-.822"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__light-first" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="50" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814v0h-1.028v0L.377 24.027v0H23.18v-.822 0"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__light-second" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="50" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814v0h-1.028v0L.377 24.027v0H23.18v-.822 0"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в HMTL-файле в тег `<head>` строку

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: они добавляются в мобильной версии, убрал margin-auto, добавил margin 0 body и получается вот это: https://pastenow.ru/3901ead201fac845626415df436871dc

Comment: не понимаю, как такое возможно, если ширина у всего .site-wrapper 320, дакое чувство, что он сжимает этот блок

Comment: @MikeL., Обновил ответ. Добавьте в HMTL-файле в тег `<head>` строку: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: огромное спасибо! Упустил такую мелочь, и возился с ней весь вечер - обидно, но теперь запомню на всю жизнь)